# Cannot add the item to shopping cart.(Magento)

Tags: magento

I get this error when I try to add a product in cart.

```
"Cannot add the item to shopping cart."
```

This is the link:

"http://www.moment-of-style.com/en/shop/coats-jackets/silk-bomber-152.html"

You can try made it.

You tell me what are the causes for this problem occurs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The reference is 404.

Comment: The reference is404.I have added a product to cart, and it added. The product is http://www.moment-of-style.com/onlajn-magazin/pal-to-pidzhaki/wool-jacket-129.html.

Answer (score 1):

To see the real reason what is causing this problem go to Admin->System->Configuration->Developer and make sure that "Log settings" is enabled.

Then try to add product one more time and when you will get the same error go into filesystem "..project_root/var/log/exception.log" and check the last error message.